# Manage Failover scenario for Azure Blob

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have a large soap xml file with at least 10000+ transactions, that is stored in an azure blob.
I am reading the xml content from azure and have to send individual transaction to the server for processing.

How can I manage the records that are read already in case when my client abruptly shutdowns.
I don't want to read all the messages from the blob again.

Is there a way to manage the indexing and resume back from the same point where I left during the exception ??

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the answer is no that there is not any function to count the bytes of having read for downloading a blob. However, you can try to realize it to count the reading byte size as indexing for resuming back.

And, the [`BlobRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrange?view=azure-java-stable) class used in the function [`download(BlobRange range, BlobAccessConditions accessConditions, boolean rangeGetContentMD5, Context context)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.bloburl.download?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_BlobURL_download_BlobRange_BlobAccessConditions_boolean_Context_) can help you to skip the content of having read to offset the previous index to continuous to read via its method [`withOffset(long offset)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrange.withoffset?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_BlobRange_withOffset_long_).

```
long offset = ...; // the indexing 
BlobRange blobRange = new BlobRange();
blobRange.withOffset(offset);
```

Hope it helps.